# One way only video stream for half duplex communication

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, gstreamer

I am testing two half duplex radios, so there can only be one way communication. I want to stream video, so I thought using UDP, because it does not require handshake. Does gstreamer, for example, have such feature? I know it has UDP, but as I understand, it still requires requests sent back to start streaming. How could I stream my webcamera video directly to some IP via UDP only?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use UDP with Gstreamer.

Here an example to stream (1) and preview (2) a videotestsrc with VP8.
To stream with a camera you need to replace videotestsrc by another element ( like v4l2src for linux, avfvideosrc for OS X , ... )

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=TRUE ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=25/1 ! x264enc key-int-max=25 tune=zerolatency ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=2 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=VP8 ! rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec ! videoconvert ! glimagesink
```

Comment: How to preview with VP8? It does not open any video window. Do I have to do something with glimagesink, to tell it where to output the video? It does open OpenGL renderer, but window is empty. For streaming I used edited videotestsrc to v4l2src device=/dev/video0 and added videoconvert after framerate

Answer (score 0):

For transmitter I use:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, width=320, height=240, framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x265enc tune="zerolatency" bitrate = 100 ! h265parse ! rtph265pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.175 port = 5000 sync = false
```

For receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0  -v udpsrc port=5000 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, encoding-name=(string)H265' ! rtph265depay ! avdec_h265 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink sync=false
```

autovideosink worked in host computer, but for receiver (RPi) it did not, so I changed it to ximagesink

I checked with Wireshark - only UDP one way communication is happening. Only receive part was for SSH.
Now I'll try to implepent it in Python, so I could receive frame and put various overlay information on top of it.